# Github and multiple origins in separate branches

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

So I have a git situation...

- There is parent repository A..
- From it, repository B is forked and introduces a large amount of divergence.
- From repository B, repository C is forked, and some more divergence is introduced.

All three are hosted on Github.

I maintain repository C for an organization. We need it to to contain a branch, let's call it `C/A`, that tracks a branch in A as it's remote, and a branch `C/B`, which tracks a branch in B as it's remote. It needs to be in this state on Github. *(This involves a really large web application which is set up to check itself out over git)*

I am able to produce a local clone of C satisfying those conditions, i.e. it has two disparate branches each of which tracks a different upstream. But Github for Windows doesn't say there is anything to sync once this is done, and I'm worried that if I recklessly issue a `git push` on the result I will mess things up beyond my current expertise to repair.

What do I do?

Comment: The biggest concern would be that you have the whole of A, and B and C within your local repo (because of a wide ref spec for their fetches) and then have a full width push of all that to your main remote, thus adding in all that other stuff. Make sure your fetch refspecs for A and B are narrow, and remove any unwanted remote branches from A and B. Then you should be good to go (though check for branch naming confusions;-).

Comment: Thanks for reassurance. :) I just wiped all the branches except the ones we're supposed to be working on, and in the end I have just two branches in repository C, and one unambiguously corresponds to C/A while another is still the same C/B that I started with.

That's not the end of the problem though. When I clone the repository again, I don't see A as a remote, and branch remotes do not appear to have changed in the on-github repository.

Do I need to do something special to get the branch metadata to change within C?